# I have problems updating and installing new paquets in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have a problem as I try to update and/or install a package on a Linux server. When I do an apt-get update, get the following:

```
N: Omitting the file "mosquitto-repo.gpg.key" from the "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" directory, as it has an invalid file name extension

N: Omitting the file "mosquitto-jessie.list.2" from the "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" directory, as it has an invalid file name extension

N: Omitting the file "mosquitto-jessie.list.3" from the directory "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/", since it has an invalid file name extension

N: Omitting the file «packages-microsoft-prod.deb» from the directory «/etc/apt/sources.list.d/», since it has an invalid file name extension

N: Omitting the file "mosquitto-jessie.list.1" from the directory "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/", as it has an invalid file name extension

N: Omitting the file "mosquitto_1.1.2.orig.tar.gz" from the "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" directory, as it has an invalid file name extension
```

I know it's something related to the /etc/sources.list file but I do not know what I have to change.
In this file I have the following:

```
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ stretch main    
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ stretch main    
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main    
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main        
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main    
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

The content in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ is the following:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us the content of "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" please ?
It seems you have some files causing some problems there.

It doesn't seem to be the "/etc/sources.list" in my opinion.

In fact, all your files there should finish in ".list", which is not the case in what you have us.

Look that : https://askubuntu.com/a/82844

UPDATE

In fact all the files which don't finish in ".list" shouldn't be there. If you have any idea how they arrived there maybe.
Anyway, you should remove them (copy them somewhere for a backup) and try again your update, it should work I think.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Okay, I will try it Thank you! @Dylage